# How to correctly show that a value isn't present in an array when performing a binary search

Tags: javascript, algorithm, binary-search

I'm trying to implement a binary search in JavaScript. I'm able to return the index of the target element, however, my program is not returning "-1" to indicate that the target value is not present in the array. For example, if I have an array of [12, 39, 52, 61, 88, 100], and I enter the target value "200" into my binary search function , it doesn't return "-1" to indicate that the value isn't present in the array even though I structured my else statement to do this. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
function binarySearch(arr, target){
var start = 0;
var end = arr.length - 1;

while(start <= end){

    var mid = Math.floor((start +  end)/2);

    if(arr[mid] < target){
        start = mid + 1;
    }

    else if(arr[mid] === target){
        return mid;
    }

    else if(arr[mid] > target) {
        end = mid - 1;
    }

    else {
        return -1;
      }
    }
  }

var myArr = [12, 39, 52, 61, 88, 100];
binarySearch(myArr, 200);
```

Comment: Write return -1 at the end of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the return value of `-1` out of the `while` loop, because if no return has happen inside the loop, you value has no been found yet. So just return `-1` at the end.

Even the last check, you could omit, after checking for smaller or equal values, the left over is always greater.

```js
function binarySearch(arr, target) {
    var start = 0,
        end = arr.length - 1,
        mid;

    while (start <= end) {
        mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
        if (arr[mid] < target) {
            start = mid + 1;
            continue;
        } 
        if (arr[mid] === target) {
            return mid;
        }
        end = mid - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

var myArr = [12, 39, 52, 61, 88, 100];

console.log(binarySearch(myArr, 200));  // -1
console.log(binarySearch(myArr, 12));   //  0
console.log(binarySearch(myArr, 39));   //  1
console.log(binarySearch(myArr, 52));   //  2
console.log(binarySearch(myArr, 61));   //  3
console.log(binarySearch(myArr, 88));  //   4
console.log(binarySearch(myArr, 100));  //  5
```